# C# Winform: Using Global Variable for FileSystemWatcher Path

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I have a form with two FileSystemWatcher controls.  The Path is set generic, and we need to deploy in multiple environments where the paths will be different.  I created a class in Program.cs with my Global variables.

Program.cs

```
public static class Global {
    public const string connString = "<connection info>";
    public const string txtWatchPath = @"c:\test";
    public const string sumWatchPath = @"C:\Import";
}
```

I had my watchers set up initially like this:

Form_Status.Designer.cs

```
// 
// txtWatcher
// 
this.txtWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.txtWatcher.Filter = "*_hdr.txt";
this.txtWatcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
this.txtWatcher.Path = Global.txtWatchPath;
this.txtWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.txtWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.txtWatcher_Changed);
// 
// sumWatcher
// 
this.sumWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.sumWatcher.Filter = "*_hdr.sum";
this.sumWatcher.Path = Global.sumWatchPath;
this.sumWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.sumWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.sumWatcher_Changed);
```

It works initially, but when I reload the project they resolve to the path instead of the Global variable.

Form_Status.Designer.cs

```
// 
// txtWatcher
// 
this.txtWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.txtWatcher.Filter = "*_hdr.txt";
this.txtWatcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
this.txtWatcher.Path = "c:\\test";
this.txtWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.txtWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.txtWatcher_Changed);
// 
// sumWatcher
// 
this.sumWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.sumWatcher.Filter = "*_hdr.sum";
this.sumWatcher.Path = "C:\\Import";
this.sumWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.sumWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.sumWatcher_Changed);
```

When I created the controls in the Designer I just set the paths to 'C:\'  I then created the Global variables, and set the .Path = Global Variable.
However, when I save the project, the global variable is resolved to the actual path.  Which means when I change the path variable on the Global Class, it will not change the path for the watcher.

Comment: In which files do you have this code?

Comment: What does it mean *Path is set generic*? You have `const ` fields to define the paths (no idea what's the use of these). The paths you show in the second snippet are the same. Dis you add a FileSystemWatcher control to the Form? Where you have already set those properties. Use a FileSystemWatcher class instead (declared in code - you don't need to add a control to a Form. I'ld make a specialized class to handle all of them).

Comment: @Steve added locations in the post.

Comment: @Jimi  When I created the controls in the Designer I just set the paths to 'C:\'  I then created the Global variables, and set the .Path = Global Variable.  However, when I save the project, the global variable is resolved to the actual path.  Which means when I change the path variable on the Global Class, it will not change the path for the watcher.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to modify the Form's `Designer.cs` file. Don't do that. Everything you write there is overwritten the first time you change something/compile. Possibly, don't use controls to create a FileSystemWatcher class. Do it in code. It's all much better.

Comment: Never edit the code inside InitializeComponent() by hand.  You will lose those changes when you open the form in the designer.  These assignments belong in the constructor of the form, after the InitializeComponent() call.